# Leaflet - How to add click event to button inside marker pop up in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic4

I am trying to add a click listener to a button in a [leaftlet](https://leafletjs.com/) popup in my ionic app.

Here I am creating the map & displaying markers, also the method I want called when the header tag is clicked is also below:

```
 makeCapitalMarkers(map: L.map): void {
    let eventHandlerAssigned = false;

    this.http.get(this.capitals).subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (const c of res.features) {
        const lat = c.geometry.coordinates[0];
        const lon = c.geometry.coordinates[1];
        let marker = L.marker([lon, lat]).bindPopup(`
        <h4 class="link">Click me!</h4>
        `);
        marker.addTo(map);
      }
    });

    map.on('popupopen', function () {
      console.log('Popup Open')
      if (!eventHandlerAssigned && document.querySelector('.link')) {
        console.log('Inside if')        
        const link = document.querySelector('.link')
        link.addEventListener('click', this.buttonClicked())
        eventHandlerAssigned = true
      }
    })
  }

 buttonClicked(event) {
    console.log('EXECUTED');
  }
```

When I click this header, **Popup Open** & **Inside if** are printed in the console, so I know I'm getting inside the If statement, but for some reason the *buttonClicked()* function isn't being executed.

Can someone please tell me why this is the current behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue like 2 hours ago.  I'm not familiar with ionic, but hopefully this will help.

Create a variable that keeps track of whether or not the content of your popup has an event handler attached to it already.  Then you can add an event listener to the map to listen for a popup to open with `map.on('popupopen', function(){})`.  When that happens, the DOM content in the popup is rendered and available to grab with a `querySelector` or `getElementById`.  So you can target that, and add an event listener to it.  You'll have to also create an event for `map.on('popupclose', () => {})`, and inside that, remove the event listener from the dom node that you had attached it to.

You'd need to do this for every unique popup you create whose content you want to add an event listener to.  But perhaps you can build a function that will do that for you.  Here's an example:

```js
const someMarker = L.marker(map.getCenter()).bindPopup(`
  <h4 class="norwayLink">To Norway!</h4>
`)

someMarker.addTo(map)

function flyToNorway(){
  map.flyTo([
    47.57652571374621,
    -27.333984375
  ],3,{animate: true, duration: 5})

  someMarker.closePopup()
}

let eventHandlerAssigned = false

map.on('popupopen', function(){

  if (!eventHandlerAssigned && document.querySelector('.norwayLink')){
    const link = document.querySelector('.norwayLink')
    link.addEventListener('click', flyToNorway)
    eventHandlerAssigned = true
  }

})

map.on('popupclose', function(){
  document.querySelector('.norwayLink').removeEventListener('click', flyToNorway)
   eventHandlerAssigned = false
})
```

This is how I targeted the popup content and added a link to it in the [demo for my plugin](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-arrowheads-example-zfxxc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the code in my question based on your answer. I've made some progress, but the method is still not being executed in my code. Could you please point out where I'm going wrong when implementing your fix?

Comment: I think your issue is right here: `link.addEventListener('click', this.buttonClicked())`.  Should be `link.addEventListener('click', this.buttonClicked)`.  When defining the function outside of the `add` or `removeEventHandler` function, you just want to refer to it, not execute it.  That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So yes you can't do (click) event binding by just adding static HTML. One way to achieve what you want can be by adding listeners after this new dom element is added, see pseudo-code below:

```
makeCapitalMarkers(map: L.map): void {
    marker.bindPopup(this.popUpService.makeCapitalPopup(c));
    marker.addTo(map);
    addListener();
}

makeCapitalPopup(data: any): string {
    return `` +
        `<div>Name: John</div>` +
        `<div>Address: 5 ....</div>` +
        `<br/><button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Click me!</button>`
}

addListener() {
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', onClickMethod
}
```

Ideally with Angular, we should not directly be working with DOM, so if this approach above works you can refactor adding event listener via Renderer.

Also I am not familiar with Leaflet library - but for the above approach to work you need to account for any async methods (if any), so that you were calling getElementById only after such DOM element was successfully added to the DOM.